# Angular2 development environment

Tags: angular, webpack

I'm developing an angular2-app, which I'm basing on the angular.io tutorial setup (it uses systemjs). My ultimate goal is to have a development environment, which has the following features:

- **Developing**

  - dev-server (like john papa's lite-server)
- **Testing**

  - unit-tests with jasmine
  - e2e-tests
  - coverage for said unit-tests
- **Deploying**

  - minification / tree-shaking
  - bundling

I've found that angular2-webpack-starter fits my needs (although it's using webpack), so I downloaded it, added my dependencies to the package.json, installed it and replaced the app-folder with my app-folder.

Upon starting I got:

`[default] /home/****/angular2-webpack-starter/node_modules/angular2-component-outlet/src/provider.d.ts:21:64
    Cannot find name 'NgModule'.
[default] Checking finished with 1 errors`

How do I fix this error? It seems like the dependency could not resolve its @angular-dependency.